# Javascript to Prevent ASP.NET button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Without using jQuery (can't get into why NOT right now) how do I disable an ASP.NET button from being "clickable" if a certain client-side condition is not met?

Comment: why aren't you able to remove the button from asp.net ? Javascript can be disabled and any advanced user will be able to click on the button if they want to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this with pure javascript.

```
if(someCondition)
    document.getElementById("buttonClientID").disable = true;
else
    document.getElementById("buttonClientID").disable = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

The button will be rendered as an `<input>` tag on the client side. Find the input using the standard JavaScript document.getElementById and set its `disabled` property to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

OnClientClick="return false;" will prevent the post back, without disabling the button. And you can add an alert('button disabled') if wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript:

`document.form1.button.disabled=true;`

or try

`document.getElementByID('myButton').disabled=true;`